# Redirect to external link in AppEngine java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, redirect, entry-point

I want to redirect to a external webpage but I don't know how to do that because in the EntryPoint I don't have Request and Response like in HttpServlets.

How can I do that?

Comment: I think `EntryPoint` is a Google Web Toolkit concept, isn't it?

Comment: I think so, I'm so newbie with java, appengine and GWT :S

Comment: Matt, you hit the nail, I was fighting against GWT, not AppEngine, then I search for GWT redirect and found the solution, is not a Request object but do the job :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GWT you can use [`Window.Location.assign(url)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#assign%28java.lang.String%29) to redirect browser to a new URL. Note: browser will load new URL and your GWT app will be closed (and all data and state lost).

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work?

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, but I'm trying to do something like that in onModuleLoad or in onSuccess of some AsyncCallback in the EntryPoint class of my project, and I don't know how to get HttpServletRequest object to invoke the sendRedirect :-S

Comment: @rubdottocom, I am not super familar with GWT but I don't think there is even a request involved when `onModuleLoad()` is called - this method seems to be invoked by the server when the module is first loaded into memory. There is no request to redirect at the time, if I am correct.